# How to pass arguments from command line to npm and grunt?

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to automate some process on my workflow and in order to do that, I need to use some variables to control the environment I'm working on.

I'll start with a simple example I'm trying to do which is a command to create a new folder and copy some boilerplate files. To do it I'm using npm and grunt, like this:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "new": "grunt new --target
},
```

**grunt.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  const target = grunt.option('target');
  console.log('Target: ', target);

  grunt.config.set('copy', {
    new: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'assets/zip',
        src: '*.zip',
        dest: 'projects/',
      }]
    },
  });
}
```

And I'm trying to call this like this:

```
npm run new --target:my-folder-name
```

> This is just a simple example, I'm running other scripts such as unzip files, rename, copy, process scss, etc...

What I expect is the task to run a copy the files to a folder called `my-folder-name` but it's not happening. The console is printing `true`, not the folder name.

What do I need to do to pass the argument to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say our contrived project directory is structured as follows:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── assets
│   └── zip
│       ├── file1.zip
│       ├── file2.zip
│       └── file3.zip
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
└── package.json
```

Then consider the following *Gruntfile.js* example that utilizes [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy):

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  const target = grunt.option('target') || 'foobar'; // default dir is `foobar`.

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');


  grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
      zips: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'assets/zip',
          src: '*.zip',
          dest: 'projects/' + target
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('copy-zips', [ 'copy:zips' ]);

};
```

#### The output via the `grunt` command.

1. If we `cd` to the project directory and run the following `grunt` command:

   ```
   grunt copy-zips
   ```

   the following folders (`projects/foobar`) are created in the root of the project directory.

   **Results Example A**

   ```
   .
   ├── ...
   └── projects
       └── foobar
           ├── file1.zip
           ├── file2.zip
           └── file3.zip
   ```

   ***Note** the default `foobar` folder has been created containing a copy of the `*.zip` files. The folder was named `foobar` because we DID NOT provide an argument via the command line.*
2. Next, If we `cd` to the project directory again and run the following grunt command:

   ```
   grunt copy-zips --target=my-folder-name
   ```

   the following folders (`projects/my-folder-name`) are created in the root of the project directory.

   **Results Example B**

   ```
   .
   ├── ...
   └── projects
       └── my-folder-name
           ├── file1.zip
           ├── file2.zip
           └── file3.zip
   ```

   ***Note** This time the  `my-folder-name` folder has been created containing a copy of the `*.zip` files because we provided the `--target=my-folder-name` argument/option.*

#### The output via the `npm` command.

Firstly let's configure the `scripts` section in the projects *package.json* as follows:

**package,json**

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "copy-zips": "grunt copy-zips"
  },
  ...
}
```

1. If we `cd` to the project directory and run the following `npm` command:

   ```
   npm run copy-zips
   ```

   we yield the same results as shown in the aforementioned **Results Example A** section.
2. Next, If we cd to the project directory again and run the following `npm` command:

   ```
   npm run copy-zips -- --target=my-folder-name
   ```

   we yield the same results as shown in the aforementioned **Results Example B** section.

   **Note:** The additional `--` option between `npm run copy-zips` and the argument `--target=my-folder-name`.

   The npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script) describe the `--` option as follows:

   > As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by [`getopt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script:

---

#### Additional note:

If you don't want to create the `my-folder-name` folder inside the `projects` folder, and instead you want to create the `my-folder-name` folder in the root of the project directory, then you can redefine the `dest` property in the `copy` task as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
  // ...

  grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
      zips: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'assets/zip',
          src: '*.zip',
          dest: target // <-----
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  // ...
```

Running the same command:

```
npm run copy-zips -- --target=my-folder-name
```

yields the following result:

```
.
├── ...
└── my-folder-name
    ├── file1.zip
    ├── file2.zip
    └── file3.zip
```